# How can i put a custom field inside this php

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

Hy, i want to count years of an actor.

The date that actor is born is stored in a custom field.

```
$date = get_field('data_nasterii');
```

Date stored in custom field is : yymmdd

How can i stick bouth togeder to make it work.

```
<?php
                 //date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
                 $birthDate = "12/17/1967";
                 //explode the date to get month, day and year
                 $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
                 //get age from date or birthdate
                 $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate[2])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate[2]));
                 echo $age ."ani";
            ?>
```

I try this but this returned me year 2012

```
<?php
         //date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
         $birthDate = get_field('data_nasterii');
         //explode the date to get month, day and year
         $birthDate = explode("/", $birthDate);
         //get age from date or birthdate
         $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $birthDate[0], $birthDate[1], $birthDate[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$birthDate[2])-1):(date("Y")-$birthDate[2]));
         echo $age ."ani";
    ?>
```

Comment: The place to do pure PHP questions is [so].

Comment: @brasofilo I just had to fiddle with a crappy misfit feed last week and get wp running with it. See my answer: Lot's of WP involved ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your date format - for whatever reason - really is `yymmdd` instead of being set to what you defined in the admin settings section:

There's the native PHP function [`date_parse_from_format()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date-parse-from-format.php) that you can use in conjunction with the core setting. Just add the following plugin and use the custom Template Tag in your templates.

```
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: Real Date Template Tag
 */

function wpse85476_to_real_date( $date, $format )
{
    static $date_format;
    empty( $date_format ) AND $date_format = get_option( 'date_format' );

    $date_parts = date_parse_from_format(
         $format
        ,$date
    );

    // Error handling
    if ( 0 < $date_parts['error_count'] )
    {
        return current_user_can( 'manage_options' )
            ? new WP_Error(
                 'date'
                ,'Wrong date format. Adjust Date Parser.'
                ,$date
            )
            : $date;
    }

    return array(
         'date_parts' => $date_parts
        ,'real_date'  => date_i18n(
             $date_format
            ,mktime( 0, 0, 0, $date_parts['month'], $date_parts['day'], $date_parts['year'] )
        )
    );
}
```

Here's how you'd retrieve a properly formatted date.

```
$date = wpse85476_to_real_date( get_field( 'data_nasterii' ), 'yymmdd' );
$real_date = $date['real_date'];
```

And here's how you would retrieve the parts for calculation:

```
$date_parts = $date['date_parts'];
```

Comment: kaiser, can you tell mee how can achive this ... http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/85444/how-can-i-count-years-from-a-specific-date-insered-in-a-custom-field

Comment: Uou, thiz' black magic!

Answer (score -2):

Thanks for answer, i resolve the problem with this :

```
<?php
         //date in mm/dd/yyyy format; or it can be in other formats as well
         $data = get_field('data_nasterii');
         $date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($data));
         //explode the date to get month, day and year
         $date = explode("/", $date);
         //get age from date or birthdate
         $age = (date("md", date("U", mktime(0, 0, 0, $date[0], $date[1],$date[2]))) > date("md") ? ((date("Y")-$date[2])-1):(date("Y")-$date[2]));
         echo $age ." ani";
?>
```

<sup>*Code based on [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3776843/376483) by "Sudhir"*</sup>

Comment: You copy/pasted the answer [from this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3776843/376483). If you do so, then be kind enough to state it (you even left the original comments in), as it else is a violation against the license. FYI: CC-BY-SA.

Comment: i do not copy, i try make it work that code with my custom field, i put in first time in top , but it retrive me year 2012. I try it for several time and finaly it worked it returned me the result i wanted. That is.

Comment: You started your answer with the code from SO - you still have the exact same comments and half of your code lines is the _exact_ same thing. What I'm trying to tell you is that you can't use code from SO without mentioning the author and the source, as this is [simply the SO/SE license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) that is set for all questions and answers - see the bottom left "cc-Wiki"-Badge on _every_ page.